# 401 error when authenticating to an Azure API App using AAD

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, adal, azure-api-apps

I have an API app that has been working fine with a Gateway Host and now that the gateway host is being deprecated I'm trying to follow the [Migration Guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/app-service-api-whats-changed/).  I've redeployed my service using the 2.8.1 SDK and can log into the service with a browser using AAD or a Microsoft account and use Swagger to test the service.  However, I'm trying to get a client to access the service using a ClientId and Secret.  The code is able to get the access token from AAD but I always get a 401 error whenever I try to access one of the service resources.

When I debug the service I see the following in the log:

```
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0 : Received request: GET https://[myService].azurewebsites.net/api/[myResource]
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Warning: 0 : JWT validation failed: IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Audiences: 'https://[myService].azurewebsites.net/'. Did not match:  validationParameters.ValidAudience: '[AAD ClientId]' or validationParameters.ValidAudiences: 'http://[myService].azurewebsites.net'.
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Information: 0 : Sending response: 401.71 Unauthorized
The thread 0x3b00 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

What appears to be the issue is that the Audience presented with the request is https but the validParameters.ValidAudiences collection only contains http.

I can't see any way of configuring the Audience and it appears that the http based audience is being set when Visual Studio 2015 creates the App Service.  Is there a way of manually editing the ValidAudience collection?

For reference my client code is:

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string app_id_url = "https://[myService].azurewebsites.net/";
        string authority = "https://login.windows.net/[myDirectory].onmicrosoft.com/";
        string clientId = "[AAD ClientId]";
        string clientSecret = "[AAD Client Secret]";
        string apiBaseUrl = "https://[myService].azurewebsites.net/";

        string aadToken = GetTokenForApplication(authority, clientId, clientSecret, app_id_url);

        var apiClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(apiBaseUrl) };
        apiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", aadToken);
        var apiResponse = apiClient.GetAsync(apiBaseUrl + @"api/[myResource]").Result;
        string apiResponseContent = apiResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        Console.WriteLine(apiResponseContent);
    }

    public static string GetTokenForApplication(string authority, string clientId, string clientSecret, string resourceUrl)
    {
        AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, false);
        ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
        AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireToken(resourceUrl, clientCred);
        string token = authenticationResult.AccessToken;
        return token;
    }
```

Comment: You need to replace the identifiers between square brackets with actual parameters from your deployment.

Comment: Thanks @MvdD, but I took the actual parameters out for the purposes of this post.  As you can see from the top of the post this used to work and now doesn't .

Comment: Hi @GraemeWilson, do you still need answer for this or you have found the solution?

Comment: @juvchan I have manually created an empty App Service in the Azure portal and then manually registered the app with AAD.  I then published my app to the App Service using VS 2015.  This seems to have worked and the service correctly authenticates clients.  I got it working at the end of a lot of tinkering and I haven't had time yet to reproduce the steps exactly so don't take this as a definitive workaround.  But it does seem like an issue with the way that VS 2015 publishes to App Services.

Comment: Are you using an second Azure application in order to authenticate native clients ?

Answer (score 11):

Your problem have something to do with the valid audiences. You may have 2 choices:

Option 1. Try to acquire the token with the WebAPI client ID as the AcquireToken method 'resource' parameter, instead of its Uri.

Option 2. If the previous method didn't work, you should have to modify the authentication settings of the App Service API, using [Azure Resources Explorer](https://resources.azure.com). Navigate to your web API, find the `authSettings` JSON document under the `config` node, and modify (after having changed to Read/Write mode) the array `allowedAudiences` to match your needs. In your case you may have to change `http` to `https`

Comment: I would also add that when Loul says to "Navigate to your web API" he means that you should use the search box at the top of the Resources Explorer. If you start to expand the providers and subscriptions before searching then it doesn't seem to work.

Ultimately I found my API under subscriptions/mysubname/resourceGroups/myresourcegroupname/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites

Answer (score 0):

In my ASP.NET 4.5 Web app I found that I had to specify the Valid Audiences to avoid a runtime exception being thrown.

```
public partial class Startup
{
    private static string _aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"];
    private static string _tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"];
    private static string _realm = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Wtrealm"];
    private static string _metadataAddress = string.Format("{0}/{1}/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml", _aadInstance, _tenant);
    private static string _authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, _aadInstance, _tenant);

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(
            new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Wtrealm = _realm,
                MetadataAddress = _metadataAddress,
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidAudiences = new string[] { "spn:" + _realm }
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```