# "Unauthorized" when invoking an API App from Azure Scheduler with Azure AD OAuth authentication

Tags: oauth, azure-active-directory, azure-api-apps, azure-scheduler

I have an API App which I have secured with Azure Active Directory authentication. Actions of this API App I want to invoke with Azure Scheduler. I entered tenant id, client id & secret into the Scheduler action.

When I schedule or run the job I get:

```
Http Action - Response from host 'xxxx.azurewebsites.net': 'Unauthorized'
```

Diagnostic application log gives me:

```
JWT validation failed: IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Audiences:
'https://management.core.windows.net/'. Did not match:
validationParameters.ValidAudience: 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx' or    
validationParameters.ValidAudiences: 'https://xxxx.azurewebsites.net'.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some digging I found [this somehow related entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34318059/401-error-when-authenticating-to-an-azure-api-app-using-aad).

So I really got into the Resource Explorer, down to the authsettings node of my API App and added the missing audience entry:

```
"allowedAudiences": [
  "https://xxxx.azurewebsites.net",
  "https://management.core.windows.net/"
],
```

Problem solved.

Comment: This worked for me. Specifically, adding the entry "https://management.core.windows.net/" got the scheduler to successfully authenticate.